# MySQL replication - Add new database

Tags: mysql, database, replication

Is there a way to add a new database to the replication without having to restart the master server? I can't seem to find a way and I would like to minimize the downtime to a minimum.

BTW, I tried using [this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/04/15/how-to-decrease-innodb-shutdown-times/) to speed up the restart. Bringing down the value close to 0 on my master takes forever, plus it adds a lot of load on the machine.

I am using MySQL 5.5.20.

Comment: Check the privileges that your replication user has, and or the perms of the mysql folder (maybe it can't create the folder for that database).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything to enable a new database for replication.  All DDL and DML statements should be recorded in the binary log, and be read by the replica and executed by the replica's SQL replication thread.

It's another story if you use [replication filtering](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-rules.html) on the master (`--binlog-do-db`) or filtering on the replica (`--replicate-do-db`).

You can use wildcards in any of these replication filtering options, so that you include (or ignore) new databases automatically if the database name matches some naming conventions you design.